# How to reduce the CPU Usage in XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have used XMPP framework for chat using openfire. But when I do ping activity in the XMPP framework the CPU usage goes over 200%. I have attached the timeprofile using Instruments.
Any suggestion how to decrease the CPU Usage.

[image]

Comment: Can some one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing xmpp processing on background queue?

Comment: Hi nikBhosale. Where should I do background queue in the framework itself or in the usage of class.

Comment: it's when you are creating xmpp stream add it on separate queue instead of main queue. But based on your screenshot I suspect there can be infinite recursive loop happening which is causing this crash.

Comment: Hi nikBhosale, Yes it is going to infinite loop but how to come out of that loop.